# Ignore columns that don't exist on Postgres insert? (useful for development purposes)

Tags: postgresql

As part of our development and testing flow, we reset our personal development database and then apply any migrations we want to submit for review. Resetting the development database involves running many `INSERT INTO (...)` statements with data used for testing.

Whenever we remove a deprecated column, we must manually update the SQL statements to remove the columns from the `INSERT INTO (...)` statements that were removed. It would be great if the insert statement could just ignore those columns. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Generating test data with raw SQL makes your tests glass-box; the test knows about your implementation. As you've discovered, this is fragile. The tests should populate the database using normal production functions, with test factories to help generating test data. For example, [FactoryBot](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md). This might require making your production code more flexible and configurable.

Comment: We have been considering moving towards something like that. Do you have any recommendations for frameworks in Node.js or Python?

Comment: I don't know about Node, but FactoryBoy is the Python equivalent. https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/